# Custom Adapter for MvxGridView

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I must implement a custom adapter for a MvxGridView.

This adapter should, depending on the binded type, inflate a view, and set an image resource.

Can I just override **GetView** in the **MvxAdapter** ?

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    var productNode = (ProductNode)this.GetRawItem(position);
    if (productNode.NodeType == ProductNodeType.Folder)
    {
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.GridFolderItem, parent);
    }
    else
    {
        View documentItemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.GridDocumentItem, parent);
        var imageView = documentItemView.FindViewById<MvxImageView>(Resource.Layout.GridFolderItem);

        switch (productNode.NodeType)
        {
            case ProductNodeType.Unknown:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Node type hasn't been initialized");

            case ProductNodeType.Image:
                // Set matching image
                break;
            case ProductNodeType.Pdf:
                break;
            case ProductNodeType.Parts:
                break;

            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    string.Format("Unhandled node type '{0}'", productNode.NodeType));
        }

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Or should I override **GetBindableView** ?

In which case I don't really know how to deal with the inflation without the parent ViewGroup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source for MvxAdpater is in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxAdapter.cs

The `GetView` methods basically are:

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

the method that the Java ListView calls. Override this if you want to override all MvvmCross Adapter behaviour.

```
 protected virtual View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, int templateId)
```

A method added by MvvmCross - just adds a parameter to the default Java method for a pre-selected ItemTemplateId for the current row. Override this if you want to overall all MvvmCross Adapter behaviour except the predefined ItemTemplateId (which is generally picked up from an AXML `local:MvxItemTemplate` binding

```
  protected virtual View GetBindableView(View convertView, object dataContext, int templateId)
```

A method added by MvvmCross - this is called within `GetView` and it either creates a new view or uses `convertView` and then makes sure that the binding has the right `DataContext` set. Override this if you want to replace the way MvvmCross gets list item views and binds them to their data context.

```
protected virtual void BindSimpleView(View convertView, object dataContext)
protected virtual View GetSimpleView(View convertView, object dataContext)
```

Two methods that are used to create and bind views when a zero `ItemTempateId` (i.e. no template) has been provided. In this case, we generally assume a simple `TextView` is shown and it's `Text` is then OneTime set to the `ToString` of the DataContext. Override this if you have something special you want to do without using ItemTemplate's

```
protected virtual View GetBindableView(View convertView, object dataContext, int templateId)
```

The method used to Get a view inflated from templateId (or reused from convertView) which has it's data-binding DataContext set to dataContext.

Internally for `convertView` reuse this method uses:

```
protected virtual void BindBindableView(object source, IMvxListItemView viewToUse)
```

which simple sets the DataContext on `viewToUse` to source.

and for the case where `convertView` can't be reused this method uses:

```
protected virtual IMvxListItemView CreateBindableView(object dataContext, int templateId)
```

which returns a brand new view with its DataContext already set.

---

Which you want to override depends on your use case... and from the method in your quesiton, I'm not sure what your use case is.

Personally, my most common use case is to just use different templateId's for different objects. To achieve that I generally override `GetBindableView` with something like:

```
  protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object dataContext, int templateId)
  {
      if (SomePredicate(dataContext))
            templateId = Resource.Layout.ListTemplateId1;
      else if (SomeOtherPredicate(dataContext))
            templateId = Resource.Layout.ListTemplateId2;
      else if (SomeOtherOtherPredicate(dataContext))
            templateId = Resource.Layout.ListTemplateId3;

      return base.GetBindableView(convertView, dataContext, templateId);
  }
```

You can see this in the "Working with Collections" sample: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Working%20With%20Collections/Collections.Droid/Views/PolymorphicListItemTypesView.cs#L42